# Is Wikipedia wrong regarding the Kundt’s tube?

Tags: waves, acoustics

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kundt%27s_tube) is the Wikipedia article on the Kundt’s tube.

It says:

> The powder is caught up in the moving air and settles in little piles or lines at these nodes, because the air is still and quiet there.

Is that correct? I thought the piles **settled in the anti nodes**, not at the nodes. What am I understanding wrong here? Maybe a different concept of node and anti node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a standing wave the term **node** refers the locations at which no change is occuring. For a transverse wave in a string in standing wave motion, the nodes are the points which don't oscillate. The **anti-nodes** are the locations which have maximum displacement of oscillation.

For a longitudinal wave in a gas, the terms are semi-ambiguous. There are two properties for the gas standing wave that we can look at: motion and pressure. It turns out that motion nodes (the gas molecules have an average zero extra velocity) are the locations of *pressure anti-nodes*. This is because near these motion nodes the gas is moving toward or away the node from each side of the node, simultaneously. This means the pressure at the motion node is increasing or decreasing in an oscillating fashion and is an anti-node.

Conversely, at the motion anti-nodes, the pressure remains constant, so that location is a pressure node.

The dust is moved by collisions with the molecules of the gas, so it will be pushed until it reaches a spot where the gas isn't, on the average, moving. So the dust in Kundt's tube collects at a motion node, or a pressure anti-node.

For either of these, the spacing of adjacent nodes (or anti-nodes) is still $\lambda/2$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the standing wave in the gas.